# onchage event not working for autoselected value

Tags: javascript

I put `selected="selected"` for mail option. When the page is rendered, it should call the `setImage` function and display the image. But it is not happening, why?
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/NWbsj/)

```js
function setImage(select){
  var image = document.getElementsByName("image-swap")[0];
  image.src = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

```html
<select name="kitchen_color" id="kitchen_color" onchange="setImage(this);">
  <option value="https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo4w.png">Google</option>
  <option value="http://yandex.st/www/1.645/yaru/i/logo.png">Yandex</option>
  <option value="http://limg.imgsmail.ru/s/images/logo/logo.v2.png" selected="selected">Mail</option>
</select><br />
<img src="" name="image-swap" />
```

Comment: Check console, it is failing to load the image

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO, the event you listen to is 'CHANGE' and there is no change since the page is loaded.
So, you will need to 'trigger' change event by yourself.

See example how to get what you want:

```
window.onload = function(){
   var kitchen_color = document.getElementById('kitchen_color');
   kitchen_color.onchange();
};
```

Or if you use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#kitchen_color').trigger('change');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z2y24thk/

Answer (score 0):

try this one after function declaration

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#kitchen_color').trigger('change');
});
```

here is updated jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/NWbsj/76/